# Testing iPhone in-app purchases in ad hoc distribution mode

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

My iphone application has in-app purchases and those have been tested using the iTunes Connect test user account.  I'm now distributing it via ad-hoc distribution to beta testers.  Is there any way to make the purchases "live" so that they can test them with their real iTunes accounts and not have to use the test account?  I'd clearly like to test this before formally submitting it to the iTunes store

Comment: Am i require to use XCOde to install App on device for In-APp Purchase testing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think they only run in sandbox mode via ad-hoc. You can't test it, but it should all work if it works through the test account.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use production products, but you can create test user accounts and distribute them so that your beta testers can test the in-app purchase components.  It's a bit tricky because they have to use the Settings App to log out and then log in from inside your application with the test user account.

Comment: Thats fine...but can i send application directly or tester have to install app via XCODE.

Comment: Testers do not have to have Xcode installed, you can export the product and send it along with the license file then they can drag the two into iTunes and sync their device.

Comment: Can you test In-App purchase using Enterprise provisioning profile?